# BIND 9 invalid zone name error

Tags: dns, bind

I'm trying to configure a DNS sinkhole server using BIND on Ubuntu for a school project. To make my sinkhole as populated as possible, I am working with a few online lists of malware domains, one of which is malwaredomainlist.com.

After downloading the list, I add it to `named.conf.baddomains`. Here's an example of how one zone looks like in this file

```
zone "baddomain.com" {type master; file "/etc/bind/db.blockeddomain"; };
```

When I test my current configuration with a few domains added by name, it works perfectly.

The problem is that BIND fails to reload after downloading the online list. I tried:

```
$ named-checkconf
```

and found out that some domains have 'invalid names' (approximately 50 domains out of 2000). Below is an example of the error:

```
/etc/bind/named.conf.sources:237: zone 'somebaddomain.com': is not a valid name
```

I tried but haven't found any correlation between the zones with invalid names.

What zone names does BIND consider invalid? Is there any way to find them beforehand and excluding them from the list?

Comment: Give the true names involved. But basically an host name is only numbers, letters and hyphens (not underscore) and no hyphens at start or end, and 1 to 63 characters long. Anything else used in A/AAAA/CNAME/PTR records will get refused.

Answer (score 0):

May be "IN" missed? 
I have so that

```
zone "antenna.ru" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/antenna.zones";
    allow-update { none; };
```

};
Also you can try an option "check-names ignore;"

Comment: also you can try an option "check-names ignore;"